# NSLog not printed in linphone related project

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog, linphone, appcode

NSLog is *sometimes* (most of the time) not getting printed in Xcode console area (both simulator and device). I'm suspecting that linphone is somehow causing this behaviour. Linphone debug is set via

```
linphone_core_set_log_level(ORTP_DEBUG);
```

but even if this line is commented out, no NSLog is shown. NSLogs, however, are visible in *system log* but no linphone log is visible there.

Did anyone encounter similar behaviour of Xcode not showing NSLogs? I'm aware of possibility of console area being hidden or All/Debugger/Target output issue.

I also use AppCode for development, and in AppCode this issue seems even more apparent.

Comment: I've never used linphone. What I've found is that if you attach to a process after it has already launched, you don't see logs in the Xcode console. Perhaps that's the way linphone works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to fix the issue is adding

```
ortp_logv_flush();
```

just after `linphone_core_set_log_level` so it becomes:

```
linphone_core_set_log_level(ORTP_DEBUG);
ortp_logv_flush();
```

Comment: ortp_logv_flush() helps but doesn't quite solves the issue always.